# Windows 7 RAID

Tags: lvm, windows-7, raid

Имеется в наличии windows 7 Ultimate, ведро с полуаппаратным raid. Два неодинаковых по размеру диска 250 и 320 гб. Как текущую конфигурацию пересадить не теряя информации на raid(думаю скорее всего не получится так как диски разные) или lvm или что-нибудь подобное, главное чтобы было зеркалирование.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно зеркалировать отдельные разделы. Пуск --> Компьютер (не левой, а правой кнопкой) --> в выпадающем меню выбираем "Управление". В открывшемся окне выбираете "Управление дисками". На появившейся вкладке увидите два диска - "Диск 0" и "Диск 1" с разделами, которые на них есть. Нажимаете правой кнопкой на "Диск 0", в выпадающем меню выбираете "Преобразовать в динамический диск". Затем повторяете те же манипуляции с "Диском 1". Затем нажимаете правой кнопкой на раздел C:, выбираете в выпадающем меню "Добавить зеркало", те же манипуляции повторяете с остальными разделами. Оставшиеся 70Гб использовать не получится. После всех проделанных манипуляций у Вас будет выбор с какого физического диска грузится, т.е. получится программный RAID-1.

**UDP**

"Диск 1" должен быть разбит точно также, как и "Диск 0".

**P.S.** Данная конфигурация не учебная, проверено на "боевых серверах".

Comment: Спасибо именно так и сделал, правда через акронис.